# Search and replace "-p"

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to search for exactly "-p" in the ids of huge html and append a counter after it i.e -p+counter. Please help.

Comment: Provide example HTML (part of it) and expected outcome.

Comment: I see you are new to the language (and maybe coding in general), my advise is: 1)retype the code, never copy/paste 2)if you don't understand the code don't use it and 3) please take more time/effort to write your questions. Oh, and welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking is to replace -p with -pXX in all ids where XX is an increasing counter, you can do it like this:

```
var id, counter = 1;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    id = elems[i].id; 
    if (id && id.indexOf("-p") != -1) {
        elems[i].id = id.replace("-p", "-p" + counter++);
    }
}
```

If you're just trying to add the text "+counter", then you can do it this way:

```
var id;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    id = elems[i];
    if (id && id.indexOf("-p") != -1) {
        elems[i].id = id.replace("-p", "-p+counter");
    }
}
```

If what you want (your original post is not very clear) is to replace only id values where the whole id is "-p", then you can use this:

```
var counter = 1;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (elems[i].id == "-p") {
        elems[i].id += counter++);
    }
}
```

OK, fourth guess at what you want (based on your comments) if you want -p replaced only if the p isn't followed by another letter:

```
var id, counter = 1;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    id = elems[i].id; 
    if (id) {
        elems[i].id = id.replace(/\-p([\W_]|$)/, "-p" + counter++ + "$1");
    }
}
```

And, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ug7VN/

A jQuery version of this last one would work like this:

```
var counter = 1;
$('[id]').each(function() {
    this.id = this.id.replace(/\-p([\W_]|$)/, "-p" + counter++ + "$1");
});
```

Comment: Aren't you going to get an error on elements w/o an `id` attribute?

Comment: will it replace id having "-priority". coz that also has -p?

Comment: Yes, if you want a more specific rule than contains -p, then you have to specify what rules you want.  Are you saying you only want it where the whole id is "-p"?

Comment: I added a third option if you're trying to replace all ids that are entirely "-p" with "-pXX" where XX is an increasing counter.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I don't think that could be what he wants, because there would only be one...

Comment: @nrabinowitz - it could be he's trying to fix bad HTML with multiple ids all the same, but the question certainly is unclear leaving us to guess.

Comment: no, i have ids like "bv-eng-priority-images",  "bv-eng-p-img", and "bv-eng-p"   I want the replacement not affect the first id but p should be incremented in both 2nd and 3rd ids

Comment: ie , i dont want the counter to come as -pXXriority in the first id ..i think now i am making myself clear

Comment: @RakeshR - So, what is the actual rule?  You want -p replaced only if the p isn't follow with another letter?

Comment: yaaa, exactly but it could be followed by a '-'

Comment: @RakeshR - OK, fourth example added to my answer that follows this rule along with a link to a working demo.

Comment: Thanks Jfiend. I am sorry for my ignorance.. i am very to programming. especially jquery

Comment: I added a jQuery version to my answer for the last algorithm.

Comment: thanks it worked.  now if i did var newcontent = $("htmlContent").clone(true); how to use the above code?

Comment: i mean i need to change the replace the ids of the html in  "newContent"

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, this should be as simple as:

```
var counter = 0;
$('[id*="-p"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr(id).replace('-p', '-p' + counter++));
});
```

**Edit:** if you only want items with an id *ending* in `-p`, you can use the following (note the different selector):

```
var counter = 0;
$('[id$="-p"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr(id).replace(/-p$/, '-p' + counter++));
});
```

Comment: will it replace id having "-priority". coz that also has -p?

Comment: Yes. Do you only want it to replace ids *ending* in `-p`?

Comment: i have ids like "bv-eng-priority-images", "bv-eng-p-img", and "bv-eng-p" I want the replacement not affect the first id but p should be incremented in both 2nd and 3rd ids i.e, i dont want the counter to come as -pXXriority in the first id ..i think now i am making myself clear

Comment: I want -p replaced only if the p isn't follow with another letter but may be followed by a '-'

Comment: Thanks nrabinowitz. I am sorry for my ignorance.. i am very to programming. especially jquery

Comment: var counter = 0;
$('[id$="-p"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr(id).replace(/\-p([\W$_])/, '-p' + counter++));
});